# Ho to fix "Some conflicts were found" when updating to 3.4.1?

Tags: android-studio

While attempting the update to 3.4.1, I get the following error. Any Idea why this is happening? I run Manjaro, and installed Android Studio from the repo.

[image: Android studio update error]

Answer (score 1):

In Majaro, open the package manager, go to preferences and select the AUR section to enable the AUR support and check the checkbox "Check for updates from AUR". Close the preferences tab and you will get the update. I hope it helps you!